# Compare two TimeStrings in XPath 1.0?

Tags: xpath, xpath-1.0

How can I compare these Strings in XPath1.0:

```
08-jul-2014 05:00:00
08-jul-2014 06:00:00
```

For example:

`08-jul-2014 05:00:00 > 08-jul-2014 06:00:00` should return `false`

`08-jul-2014 05:00:00 < 08-jul-2014 06:00:00` should return `true`

I looked at Xpath built funcions and I can't find any funciton to convert String to UTC Seconds for example...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following hack. Remove delimiters using `translate()` and use `substring()` to make it into format `yyyyMMddHHmmss` and then compare this atrocity.

```
article[number(substring(translate(translate(translate(@pub-date,'-',''),':',''),' ','') ,5,4)+substring(translate(translate(translate(@pub-date,'-',''),':',''),' ',''),2,3)+substring(translate(translate(translate(@pub-date,'-',''),':',''),' ',''),0,2)+substring(translate(translate(translate(@pub-date,'-',''),':',''),' ',''),9,6)) > number(substring(translate(translate(translate(@pub-date2,'-',''),':',''),' ','') ,5,4)+substring(translate(translate(translate(@pub-date2,'-',''),':',''),' ',''),2,3)+substring(translate(translate(translate(@pub-date2,'-',''),':',''),' ',''),0,2)+substring(translate(translate(translate(@pub-date2,'-',''),':',''),' ',''),9,6))]
```

I just realised that since you have month as string you are pretty much stuffed.

Comment: What's "20101115"? Is it a hard-coded value just for the comparison?

Comment: @Dalek I your case just copy paste the 'atrocity' to the other side of equation, and change the attribute name. Done it for you.

Comment: translate(translate(translate("08-jul-2014 05:00:00",'-',''),':',''),' ','') is working fine but substring(number(translate(translate(translate("08-jul-2014 05:00:00",'-',''),':',''),' ','') ,5,4)+substring(number(translate(translate(translate("08-jul-2014 05:00:00",'-',''),':',''),' ',''),2,3)+substring(number(translate(translate(translate("08-jul-2014 05:00:00",'-',''),':',''),' ',''),0,2)+substring(number(translate(translate(translate("08-jul-2014 05:00:00",'-',''),':',''),' ',''),9,6) returns nothing. What can be wrong?

Comment: jul is wrong. The idea is to transform date components to `number` and compare them that way but there is no way to do it for string months. I suppose you could add another 12 translates like: `translate("08-jul-2014", 'jul', '06')` for each month.

Comment: I am trying substring(number(translate(translate(translate("01-01-2014 00:00:00",'-',''),':',''),' ','') ,5,4)+substring(number(translate(translate(translate("01-01-2014 00:00:00",'-',''),':',''),' ',''),2,3)+substring(number(translate(translate(translate("01-01-2014 00:00:00",'-',''),':',''),' ',''),0,2)+substring(number(translate(translate(translate("01-01-2014 00:00:00",'-',''),':',''),' ',''),9,6) with no return either. What is the expected datetime format for this expression?

Comment: you should wrap only final concatenated value with  `number()`. expected - 20140101000000

Comment: There's a possible bug on this XPath. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24852596/xpath-1-0-timestring-comparison