# Time string comparison in XPath 1.0

Tags: xml, xpath, xpath-1.0

I've got this comparison in XPath1.0:

> number(substring(translate(translate(translate(@pub-date,'-',''),':',''),' ','') ,5,4)+substring(translate(translate(translate(@pub-date,'-',''),':',''),' ',''),2,3)+substring(translate(translate(translate(@pub-date,'-',''),':',''),' ',''),0,2)+substring(translate(translate(translate(@pub-date,'-',''),':',''),' ',''),9,6)) > number(substring(translate(translate(translate(@pub-date2,'-',''),':',''),' ','') ,5,4)+substring(translate(translate(translate(@pub-date2,'-',''),':',''),' ',''),2,3)+substring(translate(translate(translate(@pub-date2,'-',''),':',''),' ',''),0,2)+substring(translate(translate(translate(@pub-date2,'-',''),':',''),' ',''),9,6))

This compares `@pub-date` and `@pub-date2`. These Strings have this format: `dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss`.

The problem is: is `@pub-date` = `"30-07-2014 23:59:59"` and `@pub-date2` = `"30-08-2014 00:00:00"`, `@pub-date` is considered bigger than `@pub-date2`. What's wrong with this XPath?

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is summing up all the numbers in the date, so of course a date like `01-01-0000 23:59:59` will result in a higher value than `02-01-0000 00:00:00`.

What you have to do is get the date string in the order `YearMonthDayTime` that way you get a number that will be higher every second.

```
number(concat(substring(@pub-date,7,4),
substring(@pub-date,4,2),
substring(@pub-date,1,2),
translate(substring(@pub-date,12,8),':',''))) >
number(concat(substring(@pub-date-2,7,4),
substring(@pub-date-2,4,2),
substring(@pub-date-2,1,2),
translate(substring(@pub-date-2,12,8),':','')))
```

This will compare `20140730235959` with `20140830000000`

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the expression

```
translate(translate(translate(@pub-date,'-',''),':',''),' ','')
```

could be written a lot more concisely as

```
translate(@pub-date,'-: ','')
```

Secondly, and more importantly, the arguments to substring() are wrong. If you want to pull out the Y, M, and D from 30072014 then you want (5,4), (3,2), and (1,2) whereas this expression grabs (5,4), (2,3), and (0,2).